# How to handle "overflowing" Leaflet pop-ups?

Tags: leaflet

Some of my info pop-ups for my markers in Leaflet contain a lot of text (lots of linebreaks). This, in some cases, makes it go beyond the screen height, causing the user (me) to not be able to read all of it. Is there some way to make such "overflowing" pop-ups get a scrollbar? And also, naturally, keep it opened even when you remove the cursor from the marker so that it doesn't just disappear when I try to move the mouse cursor over to the scrollbar?

If not, how else would I solve this problem besides "cutting down on the info"?

Comment: Adding some screenshots would probably help in understanding your situation. Also, Leaflet Popups normally remain open after Marker click, so your sentence about popup disappearing on cursor move is confusing. Ideally provide a live reproduction case, e.g. using JSBin, JSFiddle, Plunker, etc.

Comment: They are confusingly called "tooltips" in Leaflet lingo. Screenshots are impossible for privacy reasons, but I also dislike it when people ask for unnecessary information. It isn't hard to imagine what I mean; it covers more than the screen can fit, simply.

Comment: "_I also dislike it when people ask for unnecessary information_" then please understand people disliking it when you ask for free help but you do not cooperate. What you think is unnecessary might actually be relevant or even the root cause of your issue. Finally, you can very well provide a sample / dummy data. Make sure you read the [help for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular about providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

In order to make your popup container scrollable, you need to set the [`maxHeight`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#popup-maxheight) property when you instantiate the popup:

```
var popup = L.popup({maxHeight: 225}).setContent(content);
```

Here is [a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jureboq/3/edit?js,output) with a working example.

Comment: Well, that may work for popups, but what I have is .bindTooltip(..., { maxHeight: 3 }); (the 3 is for testing) and it isn't recognised because only bindPopup has the maxHeight thing. I don't want *all* of them to be popups, because that would make the map system unusable due to constant clicking. How do I make it only be a popup if it's overflowing?

Comment: You could check the length of the content that you want to display. If it's over a certain value, use a popup, if it's under that value, use a tooltip. Also, if you don't want to click to open popups, attach a mouseover listener to the markers and open up the associated popup when the user hovers over the marker. Would that work for your case?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe. Not exactly sure what you mean. Sounds like a "hack" rather than a solution, though. I mean, is what I ask so strange, really? I frankly expected this to be the standard behaviour, without having to do anything extra.

Comment: The [Leaflet Docs on tooltips](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#tooltip) say that they are "used to display small texts on top of map layers." For large texts that require scrolling, you'd need to use a popup. From what I've read in the docs, there doesn't seem to be a built-in feature that does this automatically for you, unfortunately.